# Monodroid and adMob interstitial ads

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, admob

I've seen example in Monodroid of using admob banners to apps using JNI environment in order to communicate with java objects.

Is there an example how to implement and use admob interstitial full screen ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the newer and easier Java Binding Library rather than JNI. [Here](http://docs2.xamarin.com/android/Samples/Details/AdMob) is a sample from Xamarin on how to use Admob in Mono for Android. Java Binding Libraries enable you to create a version of the Java Library that you can call from your Mono for Android project. For more info on binding Java Libraries please follow [this link](http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29).

Comment: I've already seen that example. What it lacks is the use of Interstitial ads.